# Is that possible to assemble several options and pass to the plot function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using MATLAB to plot several figures and hope these figure use the same plot options, it looks something like this:

```
N = 20;
Fs = 200;
t = (0:N-1)/Fs;

x = sin(2*pi*10*t);
y = cos(2*pi*20*t);
z = x + y;

figure(1),clf;
subplot(311);
plot(t, x, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3);
grid on;
subplot(312);
plot(t, y, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3);
grid on;
subplot(313);
plot(t, z, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3);
grid on;
```

You can see the plot options are exactly the same. If I want to change the style, I have to change each of them. **Is that possible assemble/group them together and pass them to the plot function?**

I have tried to put them in a cell like this
plotOptions = {'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3};
It doesn't work. **The reason might be the plot functions would take the plotOptions as one paramter and thus failed to parse it**.

Comment: You could make your own function with the specified properties and call it several times with different arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a cell with the options was already a good approach. Just use `{:}`, as below:

```
opt = {'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3};
figure(1),clf;
subplot(311);
plot(t, x, opt{:});
```

Then, each element of the cell is evaluated as single argument.

Comment: Brilliant, this is just the way I wanted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with unique plotting function:

```
subplot(312);
myplot(t,y)
```

Save `myplot` function as a separate m-file.

```
function myplot(t,x)
    plot(t, x, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth', 3);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, this also is a good solution. Especially for some complicated plotting, such as adding labels, grid on, limit the range of axials, etc. It would be better to write a special function for such similar drawings.

Answer (score 2):

The cell answer is good, another option is to set the arg value to be a variable:

```
faceColor = 'b';
lineWidth = 3;

figure(1),clf;
subplot(311);
plot(t, x, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', faceColor, 'LineWidth', lineWidth);
subplot(312);
plot(t, y, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', faceColor, 'LineWidth', lineWidth);
subplot(313);
plot(t, z, 'bs-', 'MarkerFaceColor', faceColor, 'LineWidth', lineWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I agree with you, the cell answer is simple and helpful for my case. Taking the specific ones as variables is helpful for cases that the style for each plot is different.

Answer (score 2):

A very clean alternative approach would be to keep the plot command as simple as possible and manipulate the handles afterwards.

```
opts = {'Color','red','MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth',3};

h(1) = plot(t, x);
grid on;
subplot(312);
h(2) = plot(t, y);
grid on;
subplot(313);
h(3) = plot(t, z);
grid on;

arrayfun(@(x) set(x,opts{:}),h)
```

The advantage over the indeed neat [**approach by Nemesis**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673853/2605073) is, that in case you have multiple sets of properties, like:

```
opts.slimRed = {'Color','red','MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth',1};
opts.fatBlue = {'Color','blue','MarkerFaceColor', 'b', 'LineWidth',5};
```

and you want to exchange them, you just need to modify one variable

```
arrayfun(@(x) set(x,opts.fatBlue{:}),h)
```

to change the appearance of a whole set of handles `h`.

Comment: I like this method as well. Besides, the arrayfun looks very powerful.